# Add keys and values to array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(

      foreach($data as $i => $c):
            $sub[$i] = $c;
      endforeach;

);
```

What is wrong with the construction of this loop?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here..?

Comment: i would like add new keys for my array

Comment: Looks like a funky attempt to do `$arr[$sub] = $data;` or something.

Comment: depending on what the original keys are: print_r(array_values($array));

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
  $sub = array();
  foreach ($data as $i => $c):
        $sub[$i] = $c;
  endforeach;
```

or

```
  $sub = array();
  foreach ($data as $i => $c) {
        $sub[$i] = $c;
  }
```

Your code is invalid beacause you cannot use statements (like `foreach`) as array argument.

What's more, your code just copies one array into another, I don't want what's the purpose. I think you should read some good PHP manual.

Comment: @webarto true, I mentioned it. I just wanted to show valid PHP code version OP wrote in question (with foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, simply becuase it's wrong.

You can't execute code within the array() arguments.

What you want to do is to inject the data, in your empty array, like this:

```
  $sub = array();
  foreach($data as $i => $c)
        $sub[$i] = $c;
```